# HTML / CSS - Oптимизация сайта под мобильные девайсы с @media

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Посоветуйте, как оптимизировать сайт под мобильные девайсы с помощью @media.
Завершил успешно несколько проектов, но в данном случае, медиазапросы не хотят работать ни под каким соусом.

Вьюпорт в Хеаде указан:

```
<head>
        <jdoc:include type="head" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="templates/site/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!--[if IE 7]><link href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template; ?>/css/ie7only.css" rel="stylesheet" /><![endif]-->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="<?php echo JUri::root(true); ?>/media/jui/js/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    </head>
```

Но эффекта никакого от этого нет.

```css
.container {
width: 960px;
max-width: 90%;
height: 100%;
margin: auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
margin-top: 70px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
overflow: hidden;
background: white;
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

{
.container
background: red;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

У Вас закралась простецкая ошибка тут:

```
{
  .container
  background: red;
}
```

Должно быть:

```
.container {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Исправил. Всё равно не работает (кэш почистил).

Comment: проверьте последовательность. Правило под `media` должно быть ниже основного правила

Comment: Я это правило вынес в самый самый низ файла style.css

Comment: Это [работает](https://jsfiddle.net/n0tmgr2r/1/). Да оно просто не может не работать. Значит проблема где-то еще.

Comment: Какой браузер используете?

Comment: Хром и параллельно Оперу. В чём ещё может быть косяк?

Comment: Где-то есть правило для контейнера, которое перезаписывает обратно в белый цвет. Поищите через [styles inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/)

Comment: Буду искать. Спасибо. К сожалению на данный момент ни один медиазапрос не работает.

Comment: У Вас работает мой пример?

Comment: Да, на jsfiddle всё работает. Но на моём сайте нет...

Comment: Нет еще одного вьюпорта? Отключите все скрипты, проверьте. Но это уже из фантастики

Comment: Только один. Отключал уже.. Это действительно странно. Очень странно.

Answer (score 0):

здесь все работает, подозреваю, что используешь less или sass.
если я прав на счет less и sass! 
тогда надо подойти к вопросу несколько иначе.
проблема во вложености.

```
    html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}
```

попробуй добавить в медиа не только то правило которое хочешь поменять а все, и если  пишешь в less, то еще надо и родительские стили добавить, а в sass и того хуже...  надо добавить всю цепочку, у меня так было, так и исправил...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте записать без **screen and**

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
// ваш код
};
```

или же написать добавив **only**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
// ваш код
};
```